# wordpress ajax always return 0

Tags: ajax

This is my `ajax_script.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#color-submit").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            async:false,
            url:MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            success:function(response)
            {


                //var color_code=response.color;
                //var x = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(response.success);

                //alert(object);

                //alert(response['msg']);
                //$(".h1").css({"background-color":"#FF9852"});
                //console.log(color_code);

            }
        });
    });

});
```

and this is my action page

```
<?php
add_shortcode("259876985",contact);
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_practice_plugin' );
wp_enqueue_style('mystyle', plugins_url('/css/style.css',__FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('formjs', plugins_url('/js/formjs.js',__FILE__), array('jquery'));



//running ajax

// embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-request', plugins_url('/js/ajax_script.js',__FILE__), array('jquery')); 

// declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

//action for plugin
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax_submit', 'myajax_submit');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax_submit', 'myajax_submit');

function myajax_submit() {
    // get the submitted parameters
    //$color_value=$_POST['color-field'];

    // generate the response


    // response output
    $response=array();
    $response['success']='#FF8569';
    echo json_encode($response);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die();

    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"

}//function ends here



//running ajax


/** Step 1. */
function my_practice_plugin() {
    add_options_page( 'My Practice Contact Plugin', 'Practice Contact', 'manage_options', 'practice_contact','my_plugin_output' );
}

function my_plugin_output()
{
    ?>
  <h3> To use this Plugin use this shortcode: <span class='shortcode'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [259876985] </span> </h3>
    <br>
    <h2> Select Your Color for the form </h2> 


<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

            <form method="post" name="color-form" id="color-form" >
                <div class="input-group">

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" name="plus_button" id="plus_button">+</button>
                    </span>

                    <input type="text" name="color-field" class="form-control" id="color-field" value="#000000">

                    <div class="input-group-btn group-color"> 

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-box dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="select_color_button"  id="select_color_button">
                            <span class="fa fa-square" id="preview"></span> 
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li>

                                <div class="panel panel-default">

                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <span class="panel-label">Color Swatch</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="panel-body">

                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <li><div id="#FF0000" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#FF0000"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#00FF00" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#00FF00"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#FFFF00" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#FFFF00"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#0000FF" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#0000FF"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#FF00FF" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#FF00FF"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#00FFFF" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#00FFFF"></div></li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <li><div id="#EF2326" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#EF2326"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#6DBE45" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#6DBE45"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#F2EA3F" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#F2EA3F"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#344EA2" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#344EA2"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#B6519F" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#B6519F"></div></li>
                                            <li><div id="#73CDD8" class="swatch swatch-clickable" style="background-color:#73CDD8"></div></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>


                </div>
                <br />
                     <button type="button" id="color-submit" name="color-submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit  </button>
                </form>
<p id="msg"> </p>

</div>
</div>
</div>

    <?php
    }

function contact()
{
    ?>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="h1">
                    Contact us <small>Feel free to contact us</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">
                                Subject</label>

                            <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                                <option value="product">Product Support</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                            Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form>
            <legend><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Our office</legend>
            <address>
                <strong>Twitter, Inc.</strong><br>
                795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br>
                San Francisco, CA 94107<br>
                <abbr title="Phone">
                    P:</abbr>
                (123) 456-7890
            </address>
            <address>
                <strong>Full Name</strong><br>
                <a href="mailto:#">first.last@example.com</a>
            </address>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php

    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

In function myajax_submit send the headers before echoing any content

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
die();
```